# File upload functionality of Selenium web driver for non-input button without AutoIt or Skuliii

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to upload a document via Selenium WebDriver using Chromedriver. I have tried all the Action class and JavaScript stuff, but those do not work. I am assuming they do not work because those are relying on the button to be an input field, however, the upload button I'm dealing with is not. It's HTML looks like this:

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to: https://www.fedex.com/apps/printonline/#!
- Click on View Products under Marketing Material
- Click on Get Started under Brochure
- Click on Use your File to upload the file

Use Your File

I am able to click the use your file button, but I am not sure how I can upload the file.

```
driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/apps/printonline/#!");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Thread.sleep(6000);

if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//area[@alt='close']")) != null) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//area[@alt='close']")).click();
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Marketing Materials']/child::button")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Get Started - Brochures']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn fxg-btn-orange  mycomputer-upload-link']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Comment: <a name="upload-files-button" class="btn fxg-btn-orange  mycomputer-upload-link" onclick="javascript:setLinkView('Use Your File');">Use Your File</a>

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all get rid of those `Thread.sleep()`, use fluent wait with polling time, preferably as a function to locate the elements:

```
private WebElement waitFor(By locator) {
    int timeout = 10;
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(200))
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    return wait.until((driver) -> driver.findElement(locator));
}
```

Then you can click the buttons and upload the file like this:

```
    waitFor(By.cssSelector("button.view-products")).click();
    waitFor(By.cssSelector("a.get-started")).click();
    waitFor(By.cssSelector("a.get-started")).click();
    waitFor(By.cssSelector("input.file-upload")).sendKeys("path_to_my_file");
```

Notice I am using the `input` element to upload the file - I am not clicking the `a` link, as you do not need to do that. Just send the path directly to the input element.